# Using regex with Item Loader

Tags: regex, scrapy

I want to use regular expressions with an item loader, but I can't figure out how to.

Normally, it just appends to the end like so:

```
response.xpath('*xpath*').re(*expression*)
```

But with an item loader that doesn't work, tried like so:

```
Loader.add_xpath('item', '*xpath*').re(*expression*)
```

Also tried with MapCompose in the item.py but didn't get it to work either. Anyone know how to use regular expression with Item loaders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ItemLoader accepts regex with `re` keyword argument:

```
l.add_xpath('item', '*xpath*', re='*expression*')
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it tonight!